# ASP.net simple delete query, pass in string value

Tags: asp.net, sql, data-access-layer, tableadapter

```
DELETE FROM tblArtworkApprovalUsers
WHERE     (userID NOT IN (@UserIDList)) AND (approvalID =
                          (SELECT     ID
                            FROM          tblArtworkApprovals
                            WHERE      (templateID = @TemplateID)))
```

This is in my table adapter.  @UserIDList needs to accept something like:

```
2,44,12,70
```

How can I make this query accept that string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOT IN <expr>` requires an expression and not a string. So if you are passing the parameter and not constructing the SQL dynamically this cannot be done.

Alternative is to create the SQL dynamically (**while being aware of SQL Injection**):

```
string commad = @"DELETE FROM tblArtworkApprovalUsers " +
             "WHERE (userID NOT IN ({0})) AND (approvalID ="+
                          "(SELECT     ID " +
                            "FROM          tblArtworkApprovals " +
                            "WHERE      (templateID = {1})))";

command = string.Format(command, userIDList, templateID);
```

---

### UPDATE

Craig pointed to a better solution here which *does not provide much better performance (since parameters are variable and query plan does not get cached unless it is exactly the same) but help with SQL injection attack*:
[Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause/337792#337792)

Comment: Thanks!  How do I pass in a command to a table adapter though?

Comment: Here's how to parameterize an IN clause, I assume same holds true for NOT IN: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause/337792#337792

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options...

1. Dynamically create the whole SQL string and execute (like Aliostad suggests).
2. Write a stored procedure that accepts the string, parses it into a temporary table, then run your query against that temp table. A quick search will provide many ways to do this ([here](http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2005/10/26/quick-t-sql-to-parse-a-delimited-string/) is one).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [Arrays in SQL2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) and [Arrays in SQL2008](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html), depending on the version of your SQL server.